# Deploying Flask app with Docker on Elastic Beanstalk: resource creation cancelled error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am following along this tutorial for deploying a Flask app with Docker http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx1ZLAHMVBEDCOC/Dockerizing-a-Python-Web-App

I've got everything working great on local. However when i upload the code to `elastic beanstalk` and launch the app I get the following errors:

```
Creating EIP failed Reason: Resource creation cancelled
Creating security group named: xyz failed Reason: Resource creation cancelled
Stack named 'xyz-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [NewSignupTopic, StartupSignupsTable, AWSEBSecurityGroup, NewSignupQueue, AWSEBEIP]
```

I've tried modifying my choices in the upload flow -- e.g. not selecting an RDS, selecting a single instance and so on. But these don't seem relevant. Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

.

Comment: Can you post Dockerfile and/or Dockerrun.aws.json?

Comment: How many EB applications do you currently have running?

Answer (score 0):

I've also been following that tutorial and had the exact same problem. For me, it turns out that the user I had associated with the `eb` CLI did not have the appropriate privileges to create the desired resources. Make sure that you've granted DynamoDB:CreateTable and SNS:CreateTopic permissions to that user.